Kafka deployed on Heroku giving error "Not authorized to access topics"
I have deployed a Kafka on Heroku server.
The problem is that I am getting connected to the Kafka server on Heroku. The connection is successful and I am able to see all of my available topics on the Heroku server.
But when I try to produce message on one of the topics. It gives an error
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-08-20T14:52:25.903Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Metadata(key: 3, version: 6)","broker":"MY_BROKER","clientId":"MY_CLIENT_ID","error":"Not authorized to access topics: [Topic authorization failed]","correlationId":1,"size":627}

This is how i am creating the client
kafka = new Kafka(
        {
         clientId: "deanon-tool",
         brokers: [
          // Brokers
           ],
         ssl: {
           rejectUnauthorized: false,
           ca: [fs.readFileSync("./ca-cert.pem", "utf-8")],
           key: fs.readFileSync("./client-key.pem", "utf-8"),
           cert: fs.readFileSync("./client-cert.pem", "utf-8"),
          },
        });

This is the code where it throws error
   public async testConnection(topic: string): Promise<void> {
        const producer = this.kafka.producer();
        console.log("Topic", topic);
        try {
            console.log("Connecting to Kafka...");
            await producer.connect();
            console.log("Connected successfully. Attempting to send a test message...");
            await producer.send({
                topic: topic,
                messages: [{ value: "Test message" }],
            });
            console.log("Test message sent successfully");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error during Kafka test:", error);
        } finally {
            await producer.disconnect();
        }
    }

The "Connected successfully" log is logged and after that it crashes on the producer.send()
